# Cant connect my Laravel project with a local MAMP server : SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: select * from `users`)

Tags: laravel, macos, mamp, homestead

I've been trying for hours to establish a database connection between my Laravel project and a local MAMP server.

The migration works when i run the command from the terminal on my mac. When i run it inside my vagrant box, it doesn't work.

```
iMac-van-Tim:myProject timcreemers$ php artisan migrate:status
+------+--------------------------------------------+-------+
| Ran? | Migration                                  | Batch |
+------+--------------------------------------------+-------+
| Yes  | 2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table       | 1     |
| Yes  | 2019_08_19_000000_create_failed_jobs_table | 1     |
+------+--------------------------------------------+-------+
```

but when i run my application i get this error :

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory (SQL: select * from `users`)
```

When i connect to my MAMP Server on http://localhost:8888/ it shows me these settings :

```
Host    localhost
Port    8889
User    root
Password    root
Socket  /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock
```

My .env file :

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=8889
DB_DATABASE=myproject
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root
```

My config/database.php file in which i emptied the properties since the file retrieves them from the .env :

```
'connections' => [

    'sqlite' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlite',
        'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
        'prefix' => '',
        'foreign_key_constraints' => env('DB_FOREIGN_KEYS', true),
    ],

    'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', ''),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', ''),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', ''),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', ''),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', '/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock'),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'prefix_indexes' => true,
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
        'options' => extension_loaded('pdo_mysql') ? array_filter([
            PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA => env('MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA'),
        ]) : [],
    ],

    'pgsql' => [
        'driver' => 'pgsql',
        'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '5432'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'prefix' => '',
        'prefix_indexes' => true,
        'schema' => 'public',
        'sslmode' => 'prefer',
    ],

    'sqlsrv' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlsrv',
        'url' => env('DATABASE_URL'),
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '1433'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'prefix' => '',
        'prefix_indexes' => true,
    ],

],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Migration Repository Table
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This table keeps track of all the migrations that have already run for
| your application. Using this information, we can determine which of
| the migrations on disk haven't actually been run in the database.
|
*/

'migrations' => 'migrations',

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Redis Databases
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Redis is an open source, fast, and advanced key-value store that also
| provides a richer body of commands than a typical key-value system
| such as APC or Memcached. Laravel makes it easy to dig right in.
|
*/

'redis' => [

    'client' => env('REDIS_CLIENT', 'phpredis'),

    'options' => [
        'cluster' => env('REDIS_CLUSTER', 'redis'),
        'prefix' => env('REDIS_PREFIX', Str::slug(env('APP_NAME', 'laravel'), '_').'_database_'),
    ],

    'default' => [
        'url' => env('REDIS_URL'),
        'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
        'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', '6379'),
        'database' => env('REDIS_DB', '0'),
    ],

    'cache' => [
        'url' => env('REDIS_URL'),
        'host' => env('REDIS_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'password' => env('REDIS_PASSWORD', null),
        'port' => env('REDIS_PORT', '6379'),
        'database' => env('REDIS_CACHE_DB', '1'),
    ],

],
```

I've tried numerous solutions but none of them seem to work :

- adding /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock in the unix_socket property
- switching the DB_HOST between localhost and 127.0.0.1 (tried both ways)
- Restarting my MAMP server

I checked the socket path and found a mysql.sock.lock file, i don't know if this causes any issues?

```
iMac-van-Tim:bin timcreemers$ cd /Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/
iMac-van-Tim:mysql timcreemers$ ls
mysql.pid       mysql.sock      mysql.sock.lock
```

From what i've read it might has something to do with sockets, but unfortunately i know nothing about it. Can anybody explain how the vagrant box should work with the MAMP server?

In addition, is it a good practice to use both a Homestead environment AND a Mamp server for the database? Or is this needlessly complicating things?

I'm getting kind of desperate here, can anyone please point me in the right direction?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you check this [thread](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/sqlstatehy000-2002-no-such-file-or-directory-sql-select-count) on Laracasts? And also, Homestead is preferred to use.

Comment: I also followed this thread, but i kept getting the same error. I deleted the mamp server and i just use the homestead now. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

If your are using MAMP on Mac sometimes you need add a setup for the socket and use "localhost" instead 127.0.0.1

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=8889
DB_DATABASE=database_name
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=root
DB_SOCKET=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock
```

Comment: DB_SOCKET=/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock
works for me.